# I don't want to display back and forward button in my browser. Is there any solution apart from popup trick?

Tags: asp.net, browser, popup

customers does not want to allow user to use back or forward button. Just a clean page without commandbar and toolbar, same for FF an IE.
Disabling them is not an option as now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot change that kind of thing in a existing window -- the only way you can make those disappear is by opening a popup, specifying they should not appear in that popup when it's being opened.

Still, note that you should not try to disable those buttons nor have them disappear : your application should work fine with them, handle their actions -- after all, it's one of the few things users have understood in browsers...

And as a user, this is disturbing and annoying :

- I don't like popup windows -- and I'm not the only one who doesn't
- I don't like when a website tryies to take control over my browser
- It will not always work anyway.

And, as a sidenote : even if the back/forward buttons are not displayed, users can still use Ctrl+left/right or some kind of equivalent !

I know this is not easy, but **a part of your work as a web-developper is to explain your clients how Internet and web-applications work**... not the same way as desktop applications !

Comment: hi Pascal, with my co-workers we are discussing your opinion (like others). All users are not aware about the difference between desktop or internet app. Many of them suffer the consequences about digital-divide and they are ready to switch filling forms directly by paper and pen if they could do that!! I cannot ask a mechanic why not use back button. "This is not my business, I fix engines" this is the answer

Answer (score 2):

No, there's no other way.

However, this is extremely annoying behavior and should be **greatly** discouraged.  This isn't a code issue to solve...this is behavior that shouldn't be implemented at all.

My opinion here, you have a client problem not a code problem.  Whatever standard is the *expectation*, and the user has the expectation of having their back/forward buttons, break that and you break their experience.

Ever see a Windows application that **removes the taskbar**?  That's the equivalent...

Comment: thx Nick, I cannot add anything else. As many, I just arrived when 800 classes of this webapp are already written. I cannot change user's expectation. Infact, when I meet a client/customer/user for the first time I take some time to explain what a webapp is or not.;)

Answer (score 2):

If you can force your users into IE (can't believe I'm suggesting use of IE!) you can do this trick. Try running this from the command line

```
"C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" -k
```

This will force IE into kiosk (or full screen mode), similar to pressing F11 when in a usual browser session.

PS. I agree with the other answers suggesting this should be discouraged but there are instances (such as when the end user really can't be trusted) that this is a good solution.

Comment: nice. Is there a solution for FF without installing any plugins ????
PS: after IE start as kiosk, how can I do to take control of my desktop?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a reasonable way to disable the behavior. You may get rid of the buttons in various ways, but the behavior is still there (through keyboard commands, popup menus and so on).

The only reasonable way is to make your web application follow web semantics, and make the client realize this.

Answer (score 0):

many web based ERP (for example) does not tolerate people using navigation buttons. BUT these web applications handle the fact people use these buttons and do not crash. That's what you should do. If each time people use the back button, they get an error message, they will quickly stop using it.

Answer (score 0):

The solution that used to work in IE was adding a startup script with one line:

```
location.forward();
```

Comment: kerido, may you give me more details about this?